# Can I play Minecraft pocket edition with someone else on a computer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can you play Minecraft pocket edition co-op with pc? My brother plays Minecraft on his computer and I was wondering if I could play with him while on my iPad.

Comment: @CloseVoters The suggested duplicate question is outdated. As ardaozkal's answer says, there is a way.

Comment: @angussidney It may be outdated, but this is still technically a duplicate. ardaozkal should write his answer on the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MCPE can't play multiplayer with the Java edition, but you can play multiplayer with MCPE using the [Windows 10 edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/minecraft-windows-10-edition-beta/9nblggh2jhxj). You can get that free (on Mojang.com) if you have the Java version of minecraft.

Comment: PC is probably the more preferable term since Windows 10 is an app, its in beta and its not the main PC version.

Comment: @Daedric "Java Edition" helps avoid confusion between the original Java version, and the newer C++ Windows 10 version (both of which work on PCs). I think Mojang themselves often use  "Java Edition" to describe the original in comparison to the Windows 10 version.